# Erro em compilação de código C++

Tags: c++, compilação, syntax-error

Estou tentando criar um programa simples *(meu primeiro programa depois do hello world)* para inserir `nome`, `telefone` e `email`, mas quando coloco para compilar entra em erro em loop infinito.
Vou colocar os códigos aqui pra ver se alguém me socorre.

**pessoa.h**

```
#ifndef PESSOA_H
#define PESSOA_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Pessoa {
private:
    int cel; //número do celular da pessoa
    std::string nome;
    std::string email; //endereço da pessoa

public:

    Pessoa(std::string nome, int cel, std::string email);

    std::string getNome() const;

    std::string getEmail() const;

    int getCel() const;

    void printPessoa() const;

};

#endif
```

**pessoa.cpp**

```
# include <iostream>
#include "pessoa.h"

using namespace std;

//Getters

std::string Pessoa::getNome() const {
    return nome;
}

int Pessoa::getCel() const {
    return cel;
}

std::string Pessoa::getEmail() const {
    return email;
}

void Pessoa::printPessoa() const {
    cout << "Seu nome é " << nome << ", seu celular é " << cel << "e seu email é:" << email << endl;
}
```

**pessoa_main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pessoa.h"    
using namespace std;

int main() {


    Pessoa p1("Mariana", 99999999, "mmmmm@mmmmm");
    p1.print();

};
```

Answer (score -1):

Você esqueceu de criar o contrutor da classe pessoa, ele foi declarado no Pessoa.h, mas no Pessoa.cpp ele não está

```
# include <iostream>
#include "pessoa.h"

using namespace std;

Pessoa::Pessoa(std::string nome, int cel, std::string email)
{
    this->nome = nome;
    this->cel = cel;
    this->email = email;
}

std::string Pessoa::getNome() const {
   return nome;
}

int Pessoa::getCel() const {
    return cel;
}

std::string Pessoa::getEmail() const {
    return email;
}

void Pessoa::printPessoa() const {
     cout << "Seu nome é " << nome << ", seu celular é " << cel << "e seu 
     email é:" << email << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

um erro que eu percebi aqui foi que no arquivo .h e .cpp da classe a função usada pra printar os dados esta como printPessoa e na main esta apenas como print.

Answer (score -2):

### Problemas

Como foi dito por @MatheusTimmers, você não forneceu a **definição** do construtor `Pessoa(std::string nome, int cel, std::string email);` da classe Pessoa: você o **declarou** dentro da classe (quando forneceu a sua **assinatura** - tipo de retorno, nome e parâmetros de entrada), mas não forneceu a sua **definição**, onde está de fato "o que o construtor faz".

Além disso, percebi também um outro pequeno problema no seu programa: você está utilizando o nome errado para imprimir o seu objeto de tipo Pessoa na tela; ao invés de `printPessoa()` você utilizou apenas `print()`. Tudo bem, isso deve ter sido apenas um erro de digitação.

Voltando ao problema inicial (do construtor não definido para a sua classe Pessoa), quando tentei compilar o código no meu compilador, obtive o seguinte erro (que é bastante expressivo):

> /tmp/ccK6BAaV.o:pessoa_main.cp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `Pessoa::Pessoa(std::string, int, std::string)'

o que significa que, de fato, o seu compilador não encontrou a **definição** do seu construtor.

### Como solucionar o problema?

Eu sugiro que você implemente o construtor utilizando a **lista de inicialização** do construtor, ao invés de atribuir valores aos seus membros de dados da classe (`cel`, `nome` e `email`) dentro do corpo do construtor. Veja abaixo a forma otimizada de implementar o construtor, e logo após ela a forma como sugiro que você não faça.

##### pessoa.cpp - construtor usando lista de inicialização

```cpp
Pessoa::Pessoa(std::string nome, int cel, std::string email) : nome(nome), cel(cel), email(email)
{}
```

É importante notar que eu também poderia ter colocado a definição do construtor diretamente no arquivo **pessoa.h**, e tê-la omitido no arquivo **pessoa.cpp**.

##### pessoa.cpp - construtor usando atribuição de valores dentro do seu corpo

```cpp
Pessoa::Pessoa(std::string nome, int cel, std::string email)
{
    this->nome = nome;
    this->cel = cel;
    this->email = email;
}
```

No construtor acima (o segundo), os dados membros do objeto (`nome`, `cel` e `email`) sao inicializados com os valores padroes para os seus tipos (string vazio e o valor 0 para o inteiro) antes do corpo do construtor ser executado. Entao, no corpo do construtor as variáveis tem seus valores modificados para receber os argumentos na entrada do construtor. Ou seja, o trabalho é feito desnecessariamente duas vezes.

### Detalhe adicional - sempre defina o construtor padrão

Outro ponto que percebi na sua classe Pessoa é a ausência do construtor padrão. Em si mesmo, isto pode não ser um problema, mas é uma boa prática (a menos que você tenha um motivo legítimo para não fazê-lo) **definir um construtor padrão sempre que se define um outro construtor qualquer**, pois quando se define um outro construtor qualquer, o compilador não cria para você o construtor padrão. Portanto, se você tivesse de construir um objeto de tipo Pessoa usando o construtor padrão (como no exemplo abaixo), você teria um erro de compilação. Outro problema poderia acontecer caso algo tentasse criar objetos da sua classe usando o construtor padrão de modo implícito (como ao fazer `std::vector<Pessoa> vetorDePessoas(10);`).

```cpp
Pessoa p2;
p2.printPessoa(); // Erro - o construtor padrão Pessoa::Pessoa() não existe.
```

Se você não quiser fornecer uma definição personalizada para o construtor padrão e quiser apenas que ele possa ser usado, é possível usar `= default` após a declaração do construtor: isso fará com que o compilador sintetize um construtor padrão "básico" para você, que inicializa os seus membros dados com valores padrão.

##### pessoa.h - Exemplo de declaracão do construtor padrão usando `= default`

```cpp
class Pessoa {
private:
    ... // seus dados membros
public:
    Pessoa() = default;
    ... // resto do código
};
```

### Versão do código corrigido e com as sugestões implementadas

Abaixo coloquei a versão do código que você disponibilizou na sua pergunta, mas com as correções feitas e com as sugestões dos contrutores implementadas. Espero que te seja útil.

##### pessoa.h

```cpp
#ifndef PESSOA_H
#define PESSOA_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Pessoa {
private:
    int cel; //número do celular da pessoa
    std::string nome;
    std::string email; //endereço da pessoa

public:
    Pessoa() = default;
    Pessoa(std::string nome, int cel, std::string email) : nome(nome), cel(cel), email(email) {};

    std::string getNome() const;
    std::string getEmail() const;
    int getCel() const;
    void printPessoa() const;
};

#endif
```

##### pessoa.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "pessoa.h"

using namespace std;

//Getters

std::string Pessoa::getNome() const {
    return nome;
}

int Pessoa::getCel() const {
    return cel;
}

std::string Pessoa::getEmail() const {
    return email;
}

void Pessoa::printPessoa() const {
    cout << "Seu nome é " << nome << ", seu celular é " << cel << " e seu email é: " << email << endl;
}
```

##### pessoa_main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "pessoa.h"    
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Pessoa p1("Mariana", 99999999, "mmmmm@mmmmm");
    p1.printPessoa();
}
```